# Importing functions from separate file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

I am trying to import functions from one file to another.

For example
in my file 'main.py' I have the following code:

```
from helper_funcs import *
a = 10
print(square())
```

And in my file 'helper_funcs.py' I have the following code:

```
def square():
  return a*a
```

Obviously this does not work because '**a**' is not defined in my 'helper_funcs.py' file. It may be related to namespaces. Is there a way by which I can use this function with variables in my main file?

I don't want to pass variable '**a**' as an arugement.

Comment: Pass `a` as a parameter to `square`, and change the definition of `square` to `square(a)`

Comment: I mentioned I don't want to pass a as a parameter.

Comment: I know.  You should do that though.  This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: "I don't want to pass variable 'a' as an arugement."—why not? That's the right way to do this.

Comment: import `a` into `helper_funcs.py` from `main.py`

Comment: That was just an example of my real problem, because in my actual code I have too many variables to pass

Comment: Then pass it as `kwargs` or something.

Comment: @NikhilMishra, when simplifying code to post here (usually a good idea), please make sure not to _over_-simplify. It's important that the code we see accurately reflects the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try This

your function save as the square.py

```
def square(a):
  return a*a
```

In your main code import the function as follows but don't use  `from square.py import square`

```
from square import square
a = 10
print(square(a))
```

but here you pass the variable a